# Se agrega 2 veces a mi variable char[]

Tags: c++, c

estoy trabajando en un programa de polinomios, de ahi no hay mayor problema, primero relleno mi variable 'e1' valor por valor, despues reinicio mis contadores y hago el mismo proceso para 'e2' finalmente los imprimo, 'e1' se imprime correctamente, pero a 'e2' se le agrega 2 veces los valores

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como se ve en la imagen la primera cadena que ingrrese es 'e1' mientras que la segunda es 'e2' ademas mi valiable esta declarada como char[8]

anexo el codigo

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
   char e1[8] = {};
   char e2[8] = {};
   int cont = 0;
   int gf = 8;

   do{
     cout<<"x^"<<--gf<<": "; cin>>e1[cont];
     cout<<endl;
     cont++;
   }while(cont != 8);
   system("cls");
   fflush(stdin);
   gf = 8;
   cont = 0;
   do{
     cout<<"x^"<<--gf<<": "; cin>>e2[cont];
     cout<<endl;
     cont++;
   }while(cont != 8);

   cout<<e1;
   cout<<endl;
   cout<<e2;
   }
```

Muchas gracias..!! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tienes no es que lo0s datos se dupliquen, porque si pruebas tu programa con datos diferentes en los dos arreglos notarás que el problema es que al imprimir los arreglos, e1 se imprime bien, pero cuando imprime e2 no solo imprime e2, sino que imprime e2 y e1 juntos. La solución es hacer un bucle para imprimir los valores de los arreglos. Hacer un bucle por cada arreglo. El código es el siguiente :)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char e1[8] = {};
    char e2[8] = {};
    int cont = 0;
    int gf = 8;

    do {
        cout<<"x^"<<--gf<<": ";
        cin>>e1[cont];
        cout<<endl;
        cont++;
    } while(cont != 8);
    system("cls");
    fflush(stdin);
    gf = 8;
    cont = 0;
    do {
        cout<<"x^"<<--gf<<": ";
        cin>>e2[cont];
        cout<<endl;
        cont++;
    } while(cont != 8);


    //Bucles para imprimir los arreglos: 

    for(int i=0;i<8; i++){
        cout<<e1[i];
    }

    cout<<endl<<endl;

    for(int i=0;i<8; i++){
        cout<<e2[i];
    }

}
```